# SVG "instance" tree walking

Tags: svg, batik

I have the below SVG (cut down from a larger auto-generated file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="2880.0px" width="2300.0px">
  <g transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)">
    <use height="2048.2" id="outer" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 84.6, 3841.0)" width="2048.2" xlink:href="#sprite0"/>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <g id="sprite0" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1024.1, 1024.1)">
      <use height="2048.2" id="inner" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1024.1, -1024.1)" width="2048.2" xlink:href="#sprite1"/>
    </g>
    <g id="sprite1" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1024.1, 1024.1)">
      <use height="444.35" id="elem" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -368.6, -180.2)" width="335.35" xlink:href="#sprite4"/>
    </g>
    <g id="sprite4" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 167.65, 222.15)">
      <use height="401.35" transform="matrix(0.4578, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1071, -167.6615, -222.146)" width="732.55" xlink:href="#shape4"/>
    </g>
    <g id="shape4" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 366.25, 200.65)">
      <path d="M366.3 -200.65 L366.3 200.7 -366.25 200.7 -366.25 -200.65 366.3 -200.65" fill="#a9a9a9" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

My goal is to get the transform matrix for the element named *elem* which sits within *inner* within *outer* (ending with a matrix relative to outer).

I did this to get the outer and confirm it has a transform I can use (batik is initialised !!)

```java
        final SVGOMElement outer = (SVGOMElement)docAsSVGElement.getElementById("outer");
        assert outer instanceof SVGLocatable;
        assert ((SVGLocatable)outer).getCTM() != null;
        assert ((SVGLocatable)outer).getCTM().getA() != 0.0;
```

However to get to the named item *elem* - how can I walk the "GVT"? tree, rather than the SVG Document tree? Or is there some other obvious thing I'm missing (that no-one seems to be talking about)?

```java
         // this finds the definition, not the instance that is ultimately part of the visual "outer"??
        final SVGOMElement inner = (SVGOMElement)docAsSVGElement.getElementById("elem");
```

NOTE: can not use `getTransformToElement()` - because the *elem* is not in the instance tree (or seems not to be).

Answer (score 0):

One answer is to navigate the SVG tree - at each point extracting the transformation then combine them together.

Can use the [Batik AWTTransformProducer](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/parser/AWTTransformProducer.html) with the extracted *transform* attribute value to create an [AWT AffineTransform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) for each transformation.  e.g.

```java
   final String transformAttrVal = "matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 366.25, 200.65)";
   final AffineTransform transform = AWTTransformProducer.createAffineTransform(transformAttrVal);
```

then concatenate all the way down OR work from the bottom up (and preConcenate).

```
   final AffineTransform sprite0 = ...
   final AffineTransform inner = ...

   final AffineTransform combined = (AffineTransform)sprite0.clone(); // only if you need sprite0 again ..
   combined.concatenate(inner);
   combined.concatenate(nextLevelDown);
   ...
   combined.concatenate(shape4);
```

Then finally apply the combined to each of the points.